# How to model new class within class constructor in UML

Tags: uml

I'm modeling a software using UML. I have a class Person with an Address attribute which is a separate class. 
Each time there is a new Person, I need to have an Address object, so I have it written within the class Person contructor.
However the Person can leave its Address empty so in my mongo JSON Object i'll have :

 { 
 
id : "1a07b40t9748c2a90" 
fullName: "X Y",
address: {} 
}

```
class Person {
    String id;
    String fullName;  
    Address address;

    public Person(){
        this.address = new Address();
    }
}

class Address {
    String city;
    String state;  
    String country;
}
```

How should I model this in UML ?

Comment: What is your issue here? And what do you want to model? The behavior or the class?

Comment: I want to model the class diagram with Crow's Foot relationship symbols. Is the relation between the two classes : - One Mandatory to One Mandatory ? Or - One Mandatory to One Optional ?

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please explain why you are not satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you may have persons with an empty address, these empty addresses are still instances of `Address`. So the relationship on the Address side is one mandatory.

On the Person side, the relationship is one optional, because it is possible to create Address instances outside the context of a Person. So in crow's foot notation, this is the result:

[image: crowfoot]

If you're sure that Address will never be instantiated other than as part of a Person, you could make both sides one mandatory.

I have used crow's foot notation because that's what you asked for in a comment, but this is not UML notation.

Comment: Yes, the Address won't be instantiated outside of Person; Thank you for your answer. 
I got one last question, why did you say crow's foot notation is not UML notation ?

Comment: The UML notation is defined in the UML specification. The latest version (2.5.1) can be downloaded from the OMG website. You can verify that the crow's foot notation is not UML. Instead, UML uses so-called multiplicities. For example, 'one mandatory' is represented by multiplicity `1`. See the answer given by qwerty_so for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is actually too trivial, here you are:

[image]

`Person` has exactly one `Address`. I did not model the attributes in full. Not sure about the scoping (`address` might probably be private).